# Library for working with (potentially infinite) graphs defined by neighbor-list functions

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph

Here's a pattern I've used countless times across a variety of programming languages:

1. Encounter a problem which can be easily reduced to some graph algorithm.
2. Define an adjacency function: `outEdges :: MyNode -> [MyNode]`.
3. Code up some general form of said graph algorithm which takes this function as its first argument.

As an example, consider this *(purposefully inefficient)* method for computing the **edit distance** between two words.  We will count the least number of insertions and deletions necessary to transform one word into another via breadth first search.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

alphabet :: String
alphabet = ['a'..'z']

wordNeighbors :: String -> [String]
wordNeighbors word = deletions ++ insertions where
    insertions = [pre++[c]++suf | (pre,suf) <- splits, c <- alphabet]
    deletions =  [pre++suf      | (pre,_:suf) <- take (length word) splits]

    splits = zip (inits word) (tails word)

shortestDistance :: (Eq a,Hashable a)=> (a -> [a]) -> a -> a -> Maybe Int
shortestDistance edgeFunc source target =
    -- 8 lines of code where I do a breadth-first traversal,
    -- using a HashSet to track previously visited nodes;
    -- yawn...

editDistance :: String -> String -> Int
editDistance a b = fromJust $ shortestDistance wordNeighbors a b

main = print $ editDistance "cat" "can"  -- prints 2
```

The problem is, **I'm getting awfully tired of step 3.** (see `shortestDistance` above...)

I feel like I've written *the same algorithms hundreds of times.* I'd love it if I could instead just somehow utilize FGL or Data.Graph and be done with it, but as far as I can tell both ultimately require the construction of some sort of `Graph` data structure which is strict with respect to the set of all nodes.  This is an issue because in many problems, *the graph is infinite* (such as in the example above).

I specifically ask about Haskell because Haskell has such a strong focus on combinators that I somehow expected many of these algorithms to already exist somewhere.

---

**Addendum:** Here are other examples of functions I frequently write besides shortest-path:

```
-- Useful for organizing the computation of a recursively-defined
-- property of the nodes in an acyclic graph, such as nimbers.
dfsPostOrder :: (v -> [v]) -> v -> [v]
dfsPostOrder adjFunc root = ...

-- Find all nodes connected in some manner to the root node.
-- In case I know the components are finite size, but am not sure
-- of a nice way to express their contents.
-- (Note: The API below is only good for undirected graphs)
getComponent :: (v -> [v]) -> v -> Set v
getComponent adjFunc root = ...

-- Lazily organize the graph into groups by their minimum distance
-- to any of the nodes in @roots@.
-- One could use this to help incrementalize parts of e.g. a Game
-- of Life or Kinetic Monte Carlo simulation by locating regions
-- invalidated by changes in the state.
groupsByProximity :: (v -> [v]) -> Set v -> [Set v]
groupsByProximity adjFunc roots = ...
```

---

**TL;DR:**  Is there any general way to write algorithms that work on potentially infinite, potentially cyclic, directed graphs---such as one defined by an adjacency function (`Node -> [Node]` or `Node -> [(Node, Weight)]`)?

Comment: Okay, I haven't thought the details through, but would it be enough to take FGL and implement its `Graph` and `DynGraph` classes with a fully lazy structure of some sort, instead of `IntMap`?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis It looks like the typeclass was written with finite graphs in mind (e.g. the `noNodes` function), and I imagine that code that uses the typeclass makes similar assumptions.  (iow possibly worth a try, but seems dangerous)

Comment: I don't quite understand why you aren't just using your already-existing graph implementation. I feel like something important is missing.

Comment: @MarLinn it's that I keep needing stuff like this across new projects.  I could just try packaging some of my existing implementations up, but it would feel like a silly dependency for some things to have, and knowing me I'd also waste days fretting over little design decisions in the API.

Comment: Not to be a stick in he mud, but why is this being upvoted? It's well asked, sure, but asking for external resources is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Agh, you're right. :/  I guess this falls more under the scope of softwarerecs...

Comment: I fixed it. Just ask how to abstract out this pattern, rather than asking for a library to do so. If there's a library, someone may point it out. If not, someone may invent something.

Comment: @dfeuer It feels like that sort of confounds the question though, since in it I already present what I find to be a successful abstraction for solving these problems.  Perhaps the question should instead just be open to alternative ways of looking at or solving these problems? (since people clearly do manage to get by without such a library)

Comment: @ExpHP, if there's a part you get tired of writing, that means you haven't hit upon an abstraction that you can stick in a module/package of your own and use over and over. The problem with your question was that you were asking *where to find* a library. A better approach is to ask *how to write* one, but leaving things loose enough that people will feel free to let you know that you don't need to do that because someone else already did.

Comment: note: since posting the question, I actually have started working on some skeleton of a library, since upon reflection it didn't really seem that I had a good reason to be so apprehensive about doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think most "breadth-first" search algorithms are really some sort of ["best-first" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search). That is, the search frontier is placed in a priority queue
which determines the order in which the nodes are visited.

I found two packages which implement general best-first algorithms:

- [astar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/astar)
- [monad-dijkstra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-dijkstra)

Both of these modules have very generic interfaces - i.e. you supply a neighbor
function, an inter-node distance function and (in the case of A-star) a heuristic
function.

With the appropriate choice of heuristic and distance functions you might be able to map
your search into one of these algorithms.
For instance, [this patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US7313555) describes a way of employing A-star
to solve the edit distance problem.

Comment: Very nice find!  Note that not all of my problems are search problems; other frequent ones are extracting a component of finite size, or using the DFS postorder to compute a recursively-defined property of the nodes like [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) or centrality. But perhaps this suggests I should be looking for smaller, single purpose libraries. :)